# sum is not defined for kendo grid

Tags: kendo-ui, grid, kendo-grid, aggregate

I am trying to sum a column on a kendo grid, the datasource is not server side data, and the column is defined like this.

```
data-columns="[
    ...
    { 'field': 'owing', title: 'Balance Owing', format: '{0:c}', aggregates:['sum'],attributes: { style: 'text-align: right;'},groupFooterTemplate:'#= sum #' },
    ...
```

And the datasource has grouping and aggregates added like this

```
selectedTransactions.group({
    field: "company",
    aggregates: [
        { field: "owing", aggregate: "sum" }
    ]
});
selectedTransactions.aggregate([{ field: "owing", aggregate: "sum" }]);
```

I can't find anything else in kendo or anywhere saying I need to add more, but I am gettign an exception

> > Uncaught ReferenceError: sum is not defined

Comment: you're trying to get the sum of the amount of values in the column?

Comment: @Keith the values are currency, I want the sum of money owing in the selected transactions, so I want the sum of the amounts in that group of the column, grouped by company.

Answer (score 2):

What you need to do is add aggregate in your datasource:

```
 aggregate: [ { field: "owing", aggregate: "sum" } ],
```

and then in your columns add a footer template to collect the sum of the entire column:

```
 { field: "owing", title: "Total Price", footerTemplate: "Total Amount: #=sum#" }
```

Comment: `aggregate: [ { field: "owing", aggregate: "sum" } ]` is `selectedTransactions.aggregate([{ field: "owing", aggregate: "sum" }]);` 

But anyways that would give me the overall aggreagates, not a group aggregate

Comment: I am applying the aggregates in the group `selectedTransactions.group({field: "company", aggregates: [ { field: "owing", aggregate: "sum" } ] });` and the group footer template `groupFooterTemplate:'#= sum #'`

Comment: why use selectedTransactions? just use group and add the fields you need

Comment: are you grouping particular rows or just the column?

Comment: selectedTransactions is the dataSource

Comment: do it this way then dataSource: selectedTransactions,, and then add the fields and groupings that way, maybe it cant read the datasource correctly

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158189/discussion-between-andrew-and-keith).

Answer (score -1):

Here in kendo grid  sum keyword is use here as variable so you Just Declared sum variable in 
      **var sum = 0;**
top of the code
when we use sum then sum keyword declared as local variable

Comment: This makes no sense whatsoever. A single variable will not hold dozens of sums, and if so the value should be part of the datasource, which is how I understand aggregates to work in kendo, not a separate variable in my own JS.

Comment: sum, like "data", or any other field name of your dataItem, are declared by kendo before executing your template, that's why you can use them directly in the template.
https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/templates/overview